# Cakephp 4 can't connect to remote data source

Tags: mysql, cakephp, google-cloud-platform, remote-connection

maybe someone can help me out. Im using cakephp 4 and trying to connect to remote db on google cloud from a virtual host application on my local machine.

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

apache2
php7.2

mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30

I get this error showing my pc's ip address as host => 'remote_user'@'98.765.43.21'

Connection to Mysql could not be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'remote_user'@'98.765.43.21' (using password: YES)

Wierd thing is that using the same connection array, I successfuly BAKED model (with all table relations and fields) and controller, but when I hit the controller index function from browser, I get this error message.

When I debug settings array that is passed to pdo constructor (/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver.php line 100), it is the correct one, and $dsn also looks ok.

```
'google' => [
'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',            
'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
'persistent' => false,
'timezone' => 'UTC',          
'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
'cacheMetadata' => true,
'quoteIdentifiers' => false,               
'ssl_key' => '/home/user/client-key.pem',
'ssl_cert' => '/home/user/client-cert.pem',
'ssl_ca' => '/home/user/server-ca.pem',
'host' => '12.345.67.89',
'username' => 'remote_user',
'password' => '123',
'database' => 'remote_db',
'flags' => [             
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
]
```

]

Comment: Is there any chance that your local IP address has changed since you baked (e.g. if you're on a cable or DSL line, this happens from time to time)?

Comment: Nope, I can run bake command again and it will overwrite previously baked model classes.  I'm using anydesk to connect to my office pc, where I'm doing this task, but I don't think that matters at all. @GregSchmidt

Comment: So, your web server (Apache or whatever) is running on the same computer as `bake`, but cannot connect to the remote database while `bake` can? There's no obvious reason why that should be. I do notice that you're using a connection name of `google` in your configuration, yes? Are both your site and `bake` referencing that connection config?

Comment: It was the folder/user issue for certificates. Did this and it worked:
usermod -a -G www-data username

chgrp www-data /home/certFolder
chmod g+rwxs /home/certFolder

Comment: I could also connect with mysqlWorkbench without this folder permision. Wierd stuff. Thank you for your time @GregSchmidt.

Comment: Whatever user your web server process is running under was not able to read the certificates. You're presumably running both `bake` and `mysqlWorkbench` under your own user, which did have access.